# Remove repetitive words from cells of a specific column

Tags: r, split, unique, paste, stringr

I have a two-column data frame, where the first column is ids, and the second column contains a list of transport modes used for different legs of trips. I want to remove repetitive words in cells.

For example for `id`=3, I would like to have Bicycle-Train and get rid of the other Train and Bicycle.

| id | combinedmode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bicycle_Bicycle |
| 2 | Bicycle_Bicycle_Train_Walking |
| 3 | Bicycle_Train_Train_Bicycle |
| 4 | Walking |
| 5 | Bicycle_Train_Walking |
| 6 | Bicycle |

I used the following code for this purpose, however, it doesn't work.

```
df$combinedmode2 <- sapply(df$combinedmode, function(x) paste(unique(unlist(str_split(x,", "))), collapse = ", "))
```

Comment: Please show your expected output for all the rows of your sample, not just row 3.

Comment: I think your code may work if you change `str_split(x, ", ")` to `str_split(x, "_")`. You want to split the words apart at underscores `"_"`, not at comma spaces `", "`. Not sure if you want `collapse = ", "` to make the result separated by comma spaces or if maybe you want `collapse = "_"` too.

Comment: Thanks so much. I replaced the "," with "_" and it worked.